# Python: Insert variable in string for LaTeX pdf generation

Tags: python, subprocess, pdf-generation, pdflatex

Hello i am fairly new to Python and i would like to automate some latex pdf report generation. So i want to make a function that takes x numbers of string variables as input and insert them into a predefined latex text, such that it can be compiled as a report pdf. I really hope that someone can help me with this problem. I have tried doing like shown below, which obviously does not work:

```
def insertVar(site, turbine, country):
 site = str(site)
 turbine = str(turbine)
 country = str(country)

 report = r'''On %(site)s there are 300 %(turbine)s wind turbines, these lies in %(country)s'''

 with open('report.tex','w') as f:
  f.write(report)


 cmd = ['pdflatex', '-interaction', 'nonstopmode', 'report.tex']
 proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
 proc.communicate()

 retcode = proc.returncode
 if not retcode == 0:
    os.unlink('report.pdf')
    raise ValueError('Error {} executing command: {}'.format(retcode, ' '.join(cmd))) 

 os.unlink('report.tex')
 os.unlink('report.log')

insertVar('atsumi', 'ge', 'japan')
```

So i want the output of the PDF to read:
"On atsumi there are 300 ge wind turbines, these lies in japan"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start:

```
report = r'''On %(site)s there are 300 %(turbine)s wind turbines, these lies in %(country)s'''

with open('report.tex','w') as f:
   f.write(report)
```

Should be:

```
report = r'''On {a}s there are 300 {b}s wind turbines, these lies in {c}s'''.format(a=site, b=turbine, c=country)

with open('report.txt','w') as f:
       f.write(report)
```

Comment: Can i ask you a quick question related to this? i want to compile some LaTeX code which includes phrases like: \documentclass[a4paper]{jpconf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titling} how do i avoid the .format method to excluded these? {jpconf}

Comment: Python strings are immutable so you have to create a new string. Here's an example: new_string = old_string.replace("{jpconf}", "")

Answer (score 1):

Try using [str.**format()**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
report = "On {} there are 300 {} wind turbines, these lies in {}".format(site, turbine, country)
```

If you like you can use `%` instead, note, however, this is the old style:

```
report = "On %s there are 300 %s wind turbines, these lies in %s" % (site, turbine, country)
```

**Note:** I do not see the need for using a raw string in your case.